# VBA , if then statement with data and color change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, format

I am using an if then statement to change value of cell to "test' if true. I also want to change fill color if changed

```
Then Cells(myRows,"AB") = "Test"  ( how do I add fill in Orange ?)
```

Comment: start macro recorder ... change cell color ... examine the recorded code

Comment: Do you know if I add "And" or is the a way to add the color to the "test" ( comment)

Comment: google `excel cell color when content changed` ... see what comes up

Comment: Just add change don't need And statement

Comment: Cells(myRow,"AB").Interior.Color=49407

Comment: You can write [IF...THEN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/using-ifthenelse-statements) statements two ways - as you have on a single line, or put the statements after `THEN` on new lines - change to TEST and update the colour - and then finish the code block with `END IF` on a new line.

Comment: You can also leave the statement as it is, and apply an Autoformat to the entire table (applying orange fill to any cell with content "Test")

Comment: Thank you for the help.   Test was to see if I could get it to work .  I have a quarterly report that needs to be adjusted each quarter based on certain accounts and for audit purposes we need to show where data was changed.   Able to do it with a loop and a second statement with the interior color.  It was the And after the first condition of the if statement that was causing the issues.  No And needed.   Thank you all.  I will post the code tomorrow.